# where to store SHA256 key pair per user

Tags: node.js, encryption

I have a database and an API in NodeJS, I create users with web app, and each user can create/update/delete data.

To secure this a bit, I need to encrypt data of users. So what I want is creating a pair of SHA256 public private keys each time a user is created.

Actually what I do is storing thoses keys in database, by encrypting them with global SHA256 pair of key.

So, in a nutshell, I have a global pair of key to encrypt each specific pair of keys for each user.

The fact is that seems to be not really secure because finally each user have his own encryption/decryption method stored in the database.

For example I can have 2 tables :

```
User table :

id_user | firstname | lastname | encrypted_data
-----------------------------------------------
1       | John      | Doe      | QMwmuCMmI..
2       | Jane      | Doe      | QMwmuCMmI..
... 

Keys table :

id_user | public    | private
------------------------------
1       | MIICIjA.. | MIIJrT..    
2       | MIICIjA.. | MIIJrT.. 
...
```

So the link from `John Doe` to his public and private keys in simple.

A problem is that I can't ask for user to create a pair of private/public key and send me only public, because all need to be automatic, user don't have to do anything.

Another problem is that the application should be usable on any device, so the private key can't be stored in client side.

Comment: 1. SHA256 is a one way hash function it is not directly related to public or private key. There is no such thing as a SHA256 key pair. 2. Yes, this is a problem and storing data encryption keys in the same database as the ciphertext doesn't provide any security. Perhaps encrypting the storage the database is located on is enough.

Comment: So encrypting the server ? The URL of the database ? 
The fact is that data stored must be encrypted, so I need anyway something to encrypt directly the data and decrypt it on client side or just before sending it.

Comment: Is it secured enough to use the password as encryption key ? The password is not stored in text plain, and is not decryptable. So the only way to decrypt the data is to know the password ?

Comment: Encryption is a mechanism to prevent disclosure to a wide variety of system entities and those entities change depending on the type and location of encryption used. Why do you need encryption? Is this some kind of compliance requirement? Is there some kind recommendation for this from your compliance officer?

Comment: I assume that you're talking about a web application. Of course you can devise a method where a decryption key is derived from the user's password and stored in memory for the duration of the session on the client. The frontend code only receives the encrypted fields which it decrypts on its own. This is the best you can do which can still be subverted by the system administrator by delivering a malicious JS to the user on next login and sending all decrypted fields somewhere else. If you have an app instead of web app then it is similar but less targeted.

Comment: Therefore it might be easier and sufficient to either encrypt every sensitive field with the same key stored in the server config or enable harddrive encryption of your db server.

Comment: To answer your questions, the software I developed is for people who work in alternative medicines, so the data is qualified as sensitive (at least in France). The datacenters asked for encrypted data, unless they will not accept to store them. And so every user must have a different key to be sure a user cannot decrypt the data of another user with it's own key.

Comment: You are talking about "key stored in the server config", but is it really secured ? Because someone who wants to stole information can have access to server config.

Comment: User data must be encrypted and each user's data must be encrypted with a different key are entirely different requirements. I'm not familiar with France's jurisdiction, but I would guess that the first would suffice. It is extremely hard to deduce an encryption scheme where the cloud service provider would not be able to get to the data with some kind of effort. The only way I know of would be fully homomorphic encryption which nobody uses because it is too slow and there still might be some side-channel vulnerabilities.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at the Web Crypto API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API)

Comment: For portability, you could then wrap the key using the user's password when the key first generated (such as during user signup) and store the wrapped key in the database. As long as at least either the user's password or the system remains uncompromised, I believe it should be reasonably secure

Comment: Thanks @BenzStevox, I have already heard about this API but always fell uncomfortable to use it because of my little knowledge in cybersecurity. I will try this way, which seems to be a good way to go. But a question remains, how to do if a user change his password ? Or if the user forget his password, how to unwrap without it?

Comment: In my experience, I find user convinience and security to be inversly proportional. 
But if I was to handle such a case, perhaps send a server-generated user-specific key during the key creation and use it to wrap the user's key and trigger a download for this particular wrapped key for storage in external media.

Comment: You could then provide a flow where they upload the key during password reset (ofc secured using multi-factor auth), unwrap the key using the server-generated user-specific key, wrap it using the new password and replace the one in the db. (No need to replace the local copy since it's the same as was there before).

You could have redundancies for if they lose both their password and the downloaded key but that's just more security trade-offs

Comment: Well I see, the problem is that data should be accessible from computer, phone, tablet and from the one where they created the account or any other. I am not sure that solution is better than just asking for user to create key pair and send public one. This case was not my want because user need to do nothing, just use the software. Thanks for your help but I will still looking for something more "automatic"

Comment: you can try OAuth2 Procol

Answer (score 5):

You can't just store them on the server as the attacker is on the server. The malicious hacker can easily find the keys (as they are un-encrypted), download the entire database and decrypt everything.

So, your best options are storing the keys on a completely different machine and let that machine do the encryptions and decryptions. That way the attacker would first have to break into your machine, and then the extra step of into the encryption/decryption machine. Not impossible, but hopefully much harder.

Basically, nothing is un-hackable. Making something as difficult as it can be for the attacker is the way to go.

Also, even if you strictly have to store the data in a database that your main server has access to, do **NOT** store them in the same table (as shown in your example how you kept them in separate tables). Keep the indexes of all data added to the user database the same, so that index 1 of users database will result in the correct key for that index (exactly what you did).

Another option would be cryptographic hardware. I'm not familiar with this, but I do know that some companies sell hardware that perform all of your cryptographic needs.

Comment: Storing on other machine is actually the way I do to secure it a little bit more. But the encryption and decryption can't be done by this machine unless this will means multiple request with the data decrypted. So I send the keys. Why do you suggest to encrypt and decrypt the data with that other server.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This answer exposes two solutions to secure user data, but exclude *SHA256 public/private keys* from the equation (for, I believe, something more secure). It might not be an acceptable solution.

### The *"easy"* way

I believe it's how Termius does it. In this case you would use the password to secure both the account access and encrypt data.

You would end up with something like that in database:

- `id`
- `email/username`
- `password_hash` (to secure the account access)
- `...` as many fields as you want, values are encrypted using a symmetric algorithm (i.e. AES) using the ***unhashed*** password

Advantage:

- (optional) **end-to-end encryption**
  instead of doing the decryption server-side, send the encrypted data as-is to the client. It will be the client app responsibility to do the decryption before the visualization, and to encrypt everything before sending it back to the server.

Drawbacks:

- **potential data loss**
  if an user loose its password, he also looses access to **all its data**.
- **the encryption key is stored in the database**
  sure, it's hashed. If the hashing algorithm is strong enough, it could be enough security for quite some time. But for some 3 letters agencies, it might be reversable relatively fast ‍♂️

Warnings:

1. don't use the password hash as the key, only the unhashed password. Otherwise, the encryption key is stored "as-is" in your database (the password_hash field).
2. always use a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) when you compute passwords hashes (might sound obvious to say this in 2021, but still, I prefer to say it)

### Even more robust encryption

I believe this is the way ProtonMail encrypts its users' data.

When you create a Protonmail account, you need to provide two passwords: the first one is used for account login, the second one for data encryption.

Advantage**s**:

- **you don't need to store the second password in your database at all** (hashed or not).

If the data can't be decrypted, it means the second password (aka the encryption key) is incorrect, its as simple as that.

- (optional) **end-to-end encryption**
  same as described in "the easy way".

Drawback:

- **potential data loss**
  if an user looses its second password, he also looses access to **all its data**. If he looses its first password, then he just looses access to "authentication". The typical "I forgot my password" flow works here, without raising any issue related to the encrypted data.

### Measuring the pros and cons

Both solutions have a main drawback: potential data loss.

If you go for the Protonmail-like solution, I would say this drawback is compensated by a major advantage: the user is the only actor of its data's security, you store no hints about the encryption key in your database. Therefore, if you use industry-standard encryption algorithms you aren't responsible at al. Hackers would have no solution other than brute-forcing the encryption key of every user, one by one.

Plus, if you educate your users about the consequences of loosing their password, you can also claim that you are 100% unable to access their data at the same time. This is the highest possible level of data privacy, and this is what the world needs IMHO (no matter what type of data we are talking about).

Comment: Those solutions are not really the bests ones for my purpose. Users are storing sensitives information, so there is no way that data could be loose. Do you suggest something else like @divinelemon's solution ?

Comment: You could add some key recovery system using the [Shamir's Sercret Sharing|https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir's_Secret_Sharing] algorithm. First, generate a secret and a bunch of shares. Then, store a encrypted version of the encryption key (aka the password or the second password depending on the solution you want to use). Lastly, show the shares to the user (it's the same idea than recovery code used in MFA). On password recovery, ask for 2 or more shares, decrypt the data, ask for a new password, encrypt the data with the new password and redo the whole process of secret/share generation.